# How to stop my youtube-dl script from looping?

Tags: powershell

The script works but when it finishes downloading all of the videos in the playlist it will start again and download all of them a second time. 
I noticed that it will download the playlist the same number of times that there are videos in the list (eg. if playlist contains 2 videos it will download the entire playlist twice, if 3 videos 3 times ect.)

```
$Playlisturl = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL171CEFF08937AFD2"

$VideoUrls = (invoke-WebRequest -uri $Playlisturl).Links | ? {$_.HREF -like "/watch*"} | `
? innerText -notmatch ".[0-9]:[0-9]." | ? {$_.innerText.Length -gt 3} | Select innerText, `
@{Name="URL";Expression={'http://www.youtube.com' + $_.href}} | ? innerText -notlike "*Play all*"

.\youtube-dl.exe -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s' $VideoUrls.URL -x --audio-quality 0 --audio-format mp3 --geo-bypass --ffmpeg-location PATH
```

I just need to figure out a way to stop the script when it has downloaded all videos once. Also I did not write the code for the $VideoUrls variable.

Comment: as 4c74356b41 pointed out, your `$VideoUrls` collection has both the individual items AND the playlist link itself. ///// comment out the `.\youtube-dl.exe` line and then add a line with the following `$VideoUrls.URL`. you will see 3 items - the full playlist link, and each item link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it does that because you give it individual playlist videos with playlist url, you just feed it the playlist url and it will grab all the playlist videos.

```
youtube-dl -o '%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=%id%
```

https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template-and-windows-batch-files

Comment: Yes you are correct. I think the code I was using was from a few years ago before youtube-dl was able to handle playlists so well. Thanks